# Redux persist blacklist deleting reducers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

So I've got a react redux app and using the 'blacklist' parameter to not rehydrate a couple of reducers. However, upon refresh it completely removes the entire reducer rather than them being set to their initial states. The reducers initial states are fine when not using redux persist. This is the index file of the store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";

import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import rootSaga from "./sagas";

import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import logger from "redux-logger";

import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import hardSet from "redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/hardSet";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  stateReconciler: hardSet,
  blacklist: ["Alerts", "Layout", "JourneyData"]
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const middleWares = [sagaMiddleware, thunk];

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleWares, logger))
);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```